# Display one image from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I have two tables in Laravel

- **jalans**
- **jalan_images**

In one id_jalan can be many images, My relations like this

**Model Jalan**

```
// Model Jalan
public function jalanImage()
{
    // return $this->hasMany('App\JalanImage', 'id_jalan');
    return $this->hasMany(JalanImage::class, 'id_jalan');
}

public function firstImage()
{
    // return $this->hasOne('App\JalanImage', 'id_jalan');
    return $this->hasOne(JalanImage::class, 'id_jalan');
}
```

**Model JalanImage**

```
// Model JalanImage
public function jalan()
{
    // return $this->belongsTo('App\Jalan', 'id_jalan', 'id');
    return $this->belongsTo(Jalan::class, 'id_jalan', 'id');
}
```

I want to display data like title, created_at, and the first image in each id_jalan, in my Controller for display data like this

**JalanController**

```
// JalanController
public function jalan()
{
    $jalan  = Jalan::with('firstImage')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    return view('jalan.all', ['jalan' => $jalan]);
    // dd($jalan->toArray());
}
```

In my view, first image from each id_jalan not displayed, my view like this

**Blade View**

```
@foreach($jalan as $row)
   <div class="post-item clearfix">
       <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="170px">
               <a href="#">
                  <img src="{{ asset('uploads/jalan/' .$row->first_image) }}" alt="" class="img-fluid" width="150px"></td>
               </a>
               <td>
                  <h4><a href="#">{{ $row->title }}</a></h4>
                  <i class="icofont-wall-clock"></i> <time>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($row->created_at)) }}</time>
                   <p style="color: #F3591F">{{ $row->category }}</p>
                </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </div>
  @endforeach
```

When I display it with **dd($jalan->toArray());** in my controller, the first_image displayed.

How to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data for how `id_galeri` set up. Hopefully not a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow Laravel's (especially Eloquent's) advices and [best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) regarding naming convention. That means your `gallery_images` table should have `gallery_id` field instead what you have there. Believe or not, that way you'll skip lot of unforced errors and questions. I will leave you answer of how I would do it in your place:

```
// \App\Gallery::class
class Gallery extends Model
{
    public function galleryImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryImage::class);
    }

    public function firstGalleryImage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GalleryImage::class);
    }
}

// \App\GalleryImage::class
class GalleryImage extends Model
{
    public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gallery::class);
    }
}
```

Basically you can set as many as you need methods in model that returns specific relation. In `Gallery::class` here, you can see I have set one more relation that would return just first image of that gallery. In controller you'd call it with

```
public function someControllerMethod()
{
    $gallery = Gallery::with(['firstGalleryImage'])->first();
    // or
    $galleries = Gallery::with(['firstGalleryImage'])->get();
}
```

Now returned object `$gallery` or collection of `$galleries` would carry only first image related. In your case (and if you don't want to change names of fields) you need to follow [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) of how to set another model's keys as method's arguments.

Comment: i've been followed your answer, but in my view blade can't display first image.
How to display firstimage in view blade? Is it the same like "<img src="{{ asset('uploads/jalan/' .$row->image) }}"?

Comment: @Arief What is response from `$gallery->filename`?

Comment: All data to displayed, only firstimage isn't displayed. When i display to dd($galeri->toArray()) name from firstimage displayed, but i am confused to display in blade view

Comment: @Arief Is `$gallery->filename` what has to be got from database?

Comment: I will display title, created_at, and first image from join table galeris and galeri_images

Comment: @Arief Update your question with controller's method code.

Comment: @Arief `$row->first_image` is giving you object from relation defined in Jalan model. You should call it as `$row->first_image->filename` to get actual column value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  Laravel's Eloquent ORM ( Eager Loading ),
here is an example of a single Image(image) and multiple images (media) relationship.

```
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Media::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }

    public function defaultMedia()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Media::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->defaultMedia();
    }
```